# Create a string from a fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, string, pdo

I am trying to build a string made of the results from sql and I do not know how achieve this when the data from the db is bigger than 1.

I was able to do it when the result from the database is one.

```
$result = $stmt_grade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    $str ="[{$result['score_access']}, {$result['score_training']},
{$result['score_expectation']}, {$result['score_total']} ]";
```

but when I needed to loop the fetch_assoc I was not able to assign a value to variables or directly build the string.

```
while ($resultcount = $stmt_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                 $resultcount['subarea'];


        }
```

I have looked everywhere and did not find any solutions or any similar approach to find inspiration. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the second exemple you mean  $stmt_count->fetchArray(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) instead, do you?

Comment: I tried several ways but none of them worked, even with fetchArray. If you are able to find a solution or at least give a hint. It will be great!

Comment: Taking a look to the `while` it is clear that those are 2 different DB accesses, right?

Comment: Yes, Those are 2 different DB accesses, in the first one I picked one record for each variable from the db so it was easy to build the string. In the second one, I need to loop the DB as it needs more records to build the string but I can not imagine a way to do it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to do this is loop through all of the responses in a while loop, and continually append to your string using the `.=` operator.  You can tell when you run out of records because `$result` will be false.

I separated each record with a newline.  It also looked like you wanted to count results, so I added that, too.

```
$str = ""; // start with an empty string
$count = 0;
while ( ($result = $stmt_grade->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false ) {
    // increment the record count
    $count++;
    // add a new line to the output string
    $str .= "[{$result['score_access']}, {$result['score_training']},{$result['score_expectation']}, {$result['score_total']} ]\n";
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is **to name your string properly.**

And then use a proper way to create a **JSON** string. Which consists of two parts:

1. Create a array of desired structure. Or at least provide a that structure here to let us to provide you with the code.
2. Use json_encode().

Assuming you need a nested array like this

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

the code would be

```
$result = $stmt_grade->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);  
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers provided without you I could not made it. Finally, I achieved the desirable result as follow, probably it is not elegant but works:

```
 $stmt_count= $user->countbyespeciality();

                while ($resultcount = $stmt_count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    $prueba.= "{$resultcount['subarea']},";
                    $prueba2.= "{$resultcount['number']},";

            }

                $string=rtrim($prueba, ",");
                $string2=rtrim($prueba2, ",");
                $final="[{$string}]";
                $final2="[{$string2}]";
```

The output is [something,something] [1,2,] as expected.
thanks again!